# Make inline elements contain linebreak

Tags: css

I have a plugin making 2 text elements underneath each other like the first picture.

I want to add a background to the text, but only around the text and not the full width of the element. I knew I could do this by giving it a `background-color` and `display: inline`, so that is what I did.
Now the problem is that the elements are next to each other and I would love to get a linebreak between them.

I tried `elements:before{ content: "\A"; }` but it didn't work.

**Note: I can't add html to it, so can't just add a `<br>`, I can only apply styles to it.**

How it is now (without inline):
[image: without inline]

With `display: inline`:
[image: With inline]

How I want it:
[image: how I want it]

Comment: You can't add html to text or can't edit html at all? Can you re-structure your code?

Comment: I can't edit html at all, I need to add images this way:  `{
                    "title": "Name",
                    "image": "image path",
                    "description": "description",
                    "link": "link"
                }`

Answer (score 3):

You can try something with `inline-flex`. Hope this is helpful to you.

```css
span {background:rgba(0,0,0,.5); color: #fff; padding: 5px; display: inline-flex;}
div {display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>texttexttext</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I guess I have to learn some more about flex since it look to be powerfull.

Comment: @Jeremy yes this is a great approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a width? like:

```
text{
width: 20px;
background-color: red;
}
```

Hope it helps ^_^?

Comment: The names will be dynamically changed so I can't add a width to it.